# Entity Framework 5.0 throwing EntityException when trying to add row to SQLServer Database

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm making a small Entity Framework based console application where I'm trying to access an SQLServer database I have stored in my computer and Add a row to one of it's tables. Thing is when I try and run the program the db.SaveChanges(); method throws an EntityException, and even after I surround it with try/catch and the code works without any compilation errors, the data is not saved in the database and it goes into the catch code and writes the line *"Didn't work"*. Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleAchei
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var db = new AcheiEntities2())
            {

                var cliente = new Cliente()
                {
                     ID = 1,
                    NOME = "Fan 123",
                    EMAIL = "SDASDAS@gmail.com",
                    SENHA = "ASHDUASDHUAS"
                };
                try
                {
                    db.Cliente.Add(cliente);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (EntityException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Didn't work");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Connection to the Database is working A-OK. I just don't know why this exception is being thrown. I'm basing myself on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-cV_fSNMqw and he doesn't even have to surround it with try/catch. Maybe somekind of compatiblity problem? (Video uses Entity 4.0 and I'm using 5.0). Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual error message? `EntityException` could be thrown for a variety of reasons, and there may even be one or more Inner Exceptions that would also help to shed some light on the real issue.

Comment: @NathanA Hi, sorry for the delay I only have access to the code while at work. I'm not entirely sure what is the error message since i've only been working with visual for about 2 days or so but after executing this is what appears in the Output windows under the Debug option(Screenshot):

https://gyazo.com/9ac02663aa0f87377681dc99fc9000e8

Comment: @NathanA also if I remove the try/catch block this is what appears:

`An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: The underlying provider failed on Open.`

Comment: Ok so for some wild unknown reason i've just re-created the damn program and copied the code and it magically started working

Answer (score 1):

`EntityException` could be anything.

But i would change

```
var cliente = new Cliente()
{
     ID = 1,
    NOME = "Fan 123",
    EMAIL = "SDASDAS@gmail.com",
    SENHA = "ASHDUASDHUAS"
};
```

to

```
var cliente = new Cliente()
{
    NOME = "Fan 123",
    EMAIL = "SDASDAS@gmail.com",
    SENHA = "ASHDUASDHUAS"
};
```

Probably you `ID` is set with SQL Identity and you cannot set it manually

Identity is set by default when you add the Data Annotation `[Key]` or `[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

Or if you are using Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Cliente>().Property(s => s.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```